# The car won't start the battery is new, there's not even a click sound

Tags: toyota, starting, corolla

I have a corolla verso 2005 model.

The car does not start, the battery is new.
What can it be?

Comment: Tell us what still works as normal on the car.

Comment: When was the last time it started successfully?  Any changes since then?

Answer (score 1):

Are the battery cables connected properly to the battery?  This could cause the symptoms you describe, and if the battery is new, it's possible that the terminals on the ends of the battery cables didn't get tightened properly.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Exchange! We try to keep our questions and answers high quality, which means responses should address the problem directly and not just offer commentary. I know you don't have the reputation to comment on someone else's question yet, but you'll get there quickly and can post this as a comment at that time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Primarily check the seals on the terminals . Some times many companies add a transparent layer on them which can be easily overlooked .

There is a fuse box in the engine bay, The primary fuse also can be blown  . Its should be 60A above. The fuse can also be situated on the positive battery terminal.